# Calling overridden method in generic subclass in C#

Tags: c#, generics, overriding

I'm having problems with my own implementation of generic linked list. Assignment that I'm working on says that two subclasses NodeElementLong and NodeElementString must descend from base class NodeElement. In NodeElement there should be a virtual method Print which
descendant classes override and implement in their own way. When I call Print method on element of type long, for instance, the Print method within NodeElementLong subclass must be called.

Here's the code:

```
class LinearCollection<T>
{
    NodeElement<T> head = null;

    public bool Add(T element)
    {
        if (head == null)
        {
            head = new NodeElement<T>(element);
        }
        else
        {
            NodeElement<T> current = head;
            while (current.nextNode != null)
            {
                current = current.nextNode;
            }
            current.nextNode = new NodeElement<T>(element);
        }
        return true;
    }

    public NodeElement<T> Get() 
    {
        NodeElement<T> head1 = head;
        head = head.nextNode;
        return head1;
    }

    public void Print()
    {
        for (NodeElement<T> element = head; element != null; element = element.nextNode)
        {
            element.Print();
        }
    }
}

class NodeElement<T>
{
    public T element;
    public NodeElement<T> nextNode = null;

    public NodeElement() { }

    public NodeElement(T element)
    {
        this.element = element;
    }

    public virtual void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(element);
    }
}

class NodeElementLong : NodeElement<long>
{
    public override void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("This is print long: " + element);
    }
}

class NodeElementString : NodeElement<string>
{
    public override void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("This is print string: " + element);
    }
}
```

I'm just starting with C# programming and I'm not that familiar with generics, but my assignment insists on using them. When I call Print method, the virtual method is called, but I want the appropriate overridden Print method within subclass to be called. What is wrong that is invisible to me?

Thanks for your help, guys!

Cheers!

Comment: Does your assignment call for a Generic class or was that your idea?

Comment: Why do you think something is wrong? If you can tell us a bit about what is happening and what you expected to happen, it'd help us help you.

Comment: What is it doing incorrectly?

Comment: I'm sorry for that. When I call Print method, the virtual method is called, but I want the appropriate overridden Print method within subclass to be called.

Comment: Your question does not show any subclasses...

Comment: Is this not a subclass? -> class NodeElementLong : NodeElement<long>

Comment: Yes it is. A case of insufficient scrolling (or too much to scroll...)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're trying to mix two different kinds of polymorphism that do not mix well because they have opposing aims.

The point of "subclassing" aka "ad-hoc polymorphism" is to enable callers of class methods to call *the same methods* on *similar objects* and have *different things happen* because *some of the classes changed the method behaviours in an ad-hoc manner*.

The point of generics, aka "parametric polymorphism" is to enable construction of classes that *do exactly the same thing regardless of the type of the data*. That is, you want to make an AVL tree, and that AVL tree works exactly the same regardless of whether it is stuffed full of ints or strings.

You're trying to hammer those two kinds of polymorphism into each other, and it's not working. If you want to specialize behaviour, use ad-hoc polymorphism. Don't use parametric polymorphism and expect to be able to *specialize method behaviours in an ad-hoc manner* -- the whole point of parametric polymorphism is that that *does not* happen. An *AVL tree of Animals* does not have different behaviour than an *AVL tree of Giraffes*, regardless of the fact that a *Giraffe* might have different behaviour than an *Animal*.

Answer (score 3):

The reason it's not doing what you expect is that the NodeElement you're creating is actually of type NodeElement<long> (which is not the same as NodeElementLong).  To make this work you'll need to pass in the actual element type as a second type parameter

```
class LinearCollection<T, NodeType> where NodeType : NodeElement<T>, new()
{
    public bool Add(T element)
    {
        if (head == null)
        {
            head = new NodeType();
            head.Value = element;
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmmm, I'm not sure if I understand this. When I call Print method, the virtual method is called, but I want the appropriate overridden Print method within subclass to be called. Isn't there more simple solution to that?

Comment: @Expertness: You are not creating the subclass. You are creating NodeElement<T>.

Comment: Well, in that case, the whole approach to this problem is wrong. As I stated above in the description I must have 2 subclasses.

Comment: You do still have the two subclasses.....your LinearCollection would be declared as type LinearCollection<long, NodeElementLong>.  You could have a factory method which takes T and determines the appropriate NodeElement type to create the collection with.

Answer (score 1):

The whole thing about generic types is that you do not need specific implementations like this.

It seems to me like you did not grasp the concept of generics yet. Look for a good introduction to generics (search engine x will give you tons of those) and work through it carefully.

Comment: So, there is no simple way to solve this problem with generics?

Comment: No, not for your example. What are you trying to achieve? Maybe if you provide a more concrete example we can help you find another, better way.

Comment: I'm trying to achieve that the Print method would print differently according to whether an instance is of type long or string. That's the general idea and with the help of generics I thought it might work.